# CArray and const template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, mfc, constants

Is it possible to use const parameter to CArray

I am currently using CArray like this but it won't compile:

```
typedef CArray<const CString, const CString&> data_container;
```

And I always get this compile error :

> error C2664: 'ATL::Checked::memcpy_s'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'const CString *' to 'void *'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that CArray uses expects your TYPE to be non-const, so it can cast to void* (as noted by the compilation error message).

You could store const CString pointers, which would give you a const CString when dereferenced. You do have the burden of allocating/cleaning up that memory now. An alternative is to wrap a CString in a simple class, that has a "GetString" function that returns a const reference to its internal CString instance.

Comment: In other words, CArrays can modify their contents in various ways (loading from serialization, copying from another, etc), so the contents cannot be const.

Comment: Is there an alternative that would allow const content?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Those CString are not supposed to change, so const seams appropriate.

Comment: Does that mean you want to allow inserts and deletes, but disallow modifications?